# Issues retrieving content from a website using IOS 10.1 and Swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, nsurlconnection, xcode8

First please forgive me if this has been answered before. I have gone through tons of posts and none of them help me, sorta.

What I mean by sorta is that I have not tried subclassing any framework classes to hook into the certificate validation process.

I am new to Swift3.1/iOS programming and and writing an application to get acquainted with it.

I have reviewed Apple's documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW34

I have tried many settings in my Info.plist and none of them will work for me. Odd thing is it worked yesterday.

Here is the relevant text in in my Info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.net</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.0</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I have also tried

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The server has a signed certificate by their CA. I am guessing this is the problem but they are also not strictly enforcing TLSv1.2, although they are supposed to be. I have brought this to their attention but they have not yet fixed the issue. That's the really confusing part, the confusing part is it worked yesterday. I even had a working app deployed to my device. I say had because I deployed it to my device again to see if would work and it doesn't :(.

Here is the code I am using to pull the data

```
        let url = URL(string: "https://public.example.net/index.txt")
        let indexText = try! String.init(contentsOf: url!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

and I get the following error

2016-11-25 15:27:54.051 ExamleApp[12722:1108324] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “index.txt” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=https://public.example.net/index.txt}

I have tried this on both the iOS Simulator and my iPhone 6+ and get the same error. If I go to the website in Safari on the device or the simulator the site came up fine after I trusted the certificate but the app does not work.

Also the URL has been sanitized so it's not relevant to the issue if that is discovered.

thanks for looking at my issue and if you have any ideas that might be wrong please shed some light.

Tyson

Comment: Looks like the cause is certificate trust, trying to override this behavior but iOS 10 has many depreciated methods because of ATS so it is a challenge to find a way to do it. I am inching closer though.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? While I'm not getting the same error as you, I'm having similar issue and it's iOS 10 related as I can build out to my iOS 9 device without issue.

Comment: Yes, I dragged the root ca public cert to the simulator and installed it. I also did the same using Air Drop from mac to my iPhone. I used Safari on my mac to get the root ca from the SSL certificate.

Comment: What about deployment from the App Store? Does this not happen when in production deployments?

Comment: Not sure, I would guess.  I have not gotten that far let.